# How to use sed to safely find and replace every instance of a regex match?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Let's say I have an html file that contains the following scenarios;

```
1. <p style="1">test</p>
2. <p style="2"><p style="3">test</p></p>
3. <p style="4">test</p><p style="5">test</p>
4. <td style="6"><p style="7">test</p></td>
5. <td style="8"><p style="9">test</p><p style="10">test</p></td>
```

I want to develop a way to find each instance of `<p style="test">` and replace it with `<p>`. I already know that if I wanted to find each one, I would use a regex like `<p .+?>` or something similar `<p .+?(?=>)>` which would get me anything that starts with `<p`  contains any character after that, and ends in `>`.

Here's what I've tried so far;

`sed -r 's/<p .+?>\b/<p>/'`
While this works for scenario one and four just fine, it starts to get very questionable on every other scenario that would contain more than one `<p ...>`.

`sed -r 's/\b<p .+?>\b/<p>/'` This doesn't work at all.

I won't list every possible thing I've tried here as I don't think it would bring any meaningful data to someone versed in sed. I know very little about how to use it and what its capabilities are.

What's the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: `+?` is a PCRE thing and does not work with `sed -r`. You could use `[^>]+` or switch to `perl -p`, but the correct way to handle html would be a tool designed for the job; not a regex.

Comment: To replace *every* match in a line, use `s/…/…/g`.

Comment: Please include a proper sample HTML file, not just a few lines.

Comment: Thanks @Socowi! Using the method you suggested I was able to get this resolved. As far as using a tool designed for HTML, I completely agree if I only had to worry about a few elements. Unfortunately I needed this to resolve a conversion process that assigns a style to everything which would result in possibly millions of replacements that aren't just `<p>`.

Comment: @Shawn There was no need to do so. I limited the scenarios to exactly what I needed to solve.

Comment: An actual valid HTML file is needed for decent testing of answers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, a tool that actually understands HTML is a better choice than trying to hack something together with regular expressions.

Example `perl` script using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) module that strips style attributes from `p` tags:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use Data::Dumper;

# Takes the HTML file to process as a command line argument; outputs on
# standard output.

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($ARGV[0]);
die "Unable to parse '$ARGV[0]': $!\n" unless defined $tree;

# Remove style attributes from all p tags with one
foreach my $tag ($tree->look_down('style', qr//)) {
    $tag->attr('style', undef) if $tag->tag eq 'p';
}

print $tree->as_HTML(undef, ' ');
```